# Java Quartz Logging feature disable with source Code and not including Logging lib

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am developing a java app and want to use Quartz Scheduling features. I get latest version 2.2.1 and try start with documented samples. I Stopped by Logging system integration of Quartz.
My java app has not logging (use my special nonstandard logging lib) and don't want use Log4J.But Quartz request it by bellow message.
How can I setup Quartz with disabled logging feature by writing codes (no xml file or others). I don't want to include any logging jar lib to my app.

```
   SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Job.class)
        .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .build();
CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/20 * * * * ?"))
        .build();
sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

and get error

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53833', transport: 'socket'
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<init>(StdSchedulerFactory.java:303)
    at Main2.main(Main2.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<init>(StdSchedulerFactory.java:303)
    at Main2.main(Main2.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Quartz uses slf4j, you will have to configure it to use NOPLogger (No operation Logger, a "dummy log" that does nothing).
The odd part is this is the default configuration, so make sure there is not a configuration file in your project